# How to determine $x_0$ is whether a extremum point of smooth function $f(x)$ while $x_0$ is a zero of infinite multiplicity of $f'(x)$?

Tags: analysis

How to determine $x_0$ is whether a extremum point of smooth function $f(x)$ while $x_0$ is a zero of infinite multiplicity of $f'(x)$?

I'm thinking about how to determine a stationary point of a smooth function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is an extremum point or an inflection point. I think find the zeros of its derivative $f'(x)$ would be useful. If the multiplicity of the zero is finite, then the situation is easy to deal with.

But I have no idea when meeting the zero of infinite multiplicity. For example, consider the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},\ x\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
which reaches $0$ at $x_0=0$ in supplement. Then $f(x)$ is a smooth function and $0$ is a zero of infinite multiplicity of $f'(x)$. It's trivial to see $0$ is a minimum point of $f(x)$, but I wonder if there are some methods to get the conclusion through derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it seems that I think something wrong. It's always useful to consider the derivative $f'(x)$ around $x_0$ but not only $f'(x_0)$.